# How to use google captcha when network block google.com

Tags: asp.net, webforms, recaptcha, captcha

number of user used our website portal for using our service.
Recently we have enable google captcha v2 and its working fine. however some of our clients not able to use our sites **b/c there are not allowing internet to their employee** and captcha is blocked or its not showing.
they are not convinced **to allow internet on their network** b/c of their policy but they agreed to allow some custom URl .

any work arround for this scenario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its near impossible to make a local call from your server to google, and act as the middle man - to communicate with your client - even if you do that probably google recognize you as attacker.

The solution is very simple, use a captcha from existing free source code in the Internet direct on your site.

Here are some:

https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5947/CAPTCHA-Image

https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/13209/A-CAPTCHA-Control-for-ASP-NET

Comment: sir i want to use google captcha i dont want to use some other customized or hand made captcha

Answer (score -1):

yes its near to impossible 
 
**however middle ware or  proxy server should do the trick**